# How to show huge data in listview in android using Async without OnScrollListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I want to show huge data (+50,000 records) in android listview using Async.

The data comes from web services(dot net) in pages(1000 records in each page).
As I get 1000 records I have to update the listview automatically (without scrolling).This process continues till all the records are fetched.

Am able to fetch all the records but unable to update listview.

My code is :

```
class XYZ extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        for(int i=1;i<=noOfPagesFromServer;i++)
        {   
            String url="http://182.72.123.138:9523/Service.svc/GetData/"+i;  

            try
            {
                HttpGet get =new HttpGet(url );
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                String responseString = stringBuilder.toString();
                JSONObject serverJSONObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray serverJSONArray = serverJSONObj .getJSONArray("ABC");
                for(int l=0;l<serverJSONArray.length();l++)
                {
                    JSONObject tempJSONObject=serverJSONArray.getJSONObject(l);
                    a   = tempJSONObject.getString("A");
                    b   =tempJSONObject.getString("B");
                    Model model=new Model(a,b);

                    arrayList.add(model);}
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(null);
            SystemClock.sleep(6000);
        }return null;}



          protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    { 

        super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
        adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this,R.layout.row,arrayList); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter1); 
        listView.this.adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }  


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{
            super.onPostExecute(result);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this,R.layout.row,arrayList);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }
                });

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You can use onProgressUpdate() and acheive the required result...update your model once you receive the 1000 records and update the list...

Comment: I have implemented onProgressUpdate() but still my list is not getting updated.

Comment: you need to publish the progress once you fetch 1000 records...and update the Model/Data in onprogressupdate() followed by notifyDatasetchanged...have you implemented in the same flow? Please post the implemented code...

Comment: protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

super.onProgressUpdate(values);
adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this,R.layout.row,arrayList);

listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
listView.this.adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Comment: For calling above onProgressUpdate() from doInBackground(String... params) am using : 
publishProgress(null);SystemClock.sleep(6000);

Comment: How are you identifying the completion of 1000 records...could you please post the entire updated code once...

Comment: I have updated the code which I have posted on top..Kindly check

Comment: are you using the same arraylist in the Adapter? If so, please avoid using the same...

Comment: Yes Am using same arraylist in Adapter.How does that matter ?